# How to obtain the visible extent of a SceneView?

Tags: extents, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-scene

Using the ArcGIS JavaScript API v4.24 it's possible to get the [Extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html#extent) of a SceneView::

> The extent represents the visible portion of a map within the view

This works as expected in a 2D MapView, or in a SceneView as viewed from above. But when tipping the SceneView over into 3D perspective, the `extent` no longer matches the visible extent.

To illustrate, [this sample](https://codepen.io/slead/pen/jOKEZdJ) draws a red polygon on the scene to represent the `SceneView.extent` boundaries. Use the right mouse-button to tip the scene into perspective view:

[image: screenshot of 3D scene]

Note that the rectangle represents the extent of the 2D map as viewed from above, not the scene as viewed in 3D perspective view.

Is it possible to obtain the true visible extent of the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this limitation is covered by the disclaimer on the Scene Extent page:

> Traditional 2D mapping properties, such as scale, zoom, center and
> extent do not always work well in 3D... The SceneView therefore
> supports these properties on a best effort basis, with certain
> limitations... The nature of 3D viewing includes oblique views,
> z-values, and rotation, all of which add complexity to defining what
> is visible in the view